# Forward declaring class with templated code

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration, double-dispatch

I'm trying to implement the double dispatch pattern for a message interface in C++. However, I find that I have to be too verbose in my handler class due to having to forward declare each message.

I'm looking for a way to structure the file(s) to be able to omit the forward declarations.

I'm aware that I can template the MessageHandler class with a tuple of all available messages. However, I found this not straightforward enough and looking for more simple - explainable - methods.

```cpp
struct MessageA;
struct MessageB;
// etc...

class MessageHandler {
public:
    virtual void handle(MessageA& m);
    virtual void handle(MessageB& m);
    // etc...

    virtual void handle(Message&) {}

};

struct Message {
    virtual void dispatch(MessageHandler&) = 0;
};

template<typename ActualMessage>
struct MessageHelper : Message {
    void dispatch(MessageHandler& handler)
    {
        handler.handle(static_cast<ActualMessage&>(*this));
    }
};


struct MessageA : MessageHelper<MessageA> {};
struct MessageB : MessageHelper<MessageB> {};
// etc...
```

In the real code I'm dealing with more than 20 messages. I'm okay with the verbosity of the handler class, the forward declarations are a bit "much".

Is there some way I can restructure this? Of course I'm limited due to the fact that the MessageHelper class is templated. This restricts me in forward declaring the MessageHandler class instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, the implementation of MessageHandler is found in the respective cpp file.

Comment: IMO not enough info. This looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I'm suspecting you need use CRTP to solve it.

Comment: Could you explain how this API supposed to be used? How handlers are called? Why dynamic polymorphism is needed?

Comment: @MarekR I may have confused you by my typo in the code block. I fixed it now.

Comment: @MarekR I need polymorphism because I want to be able to pass various messages around in the application. I want handler to be able to filter the messages they handle, this is done by only overloading the handle() method for the messages a specific handler is interested in.

I'm planning on having a list of handlers, so I'm dispatching each message to all of them.

My question was already answered. However, I always appreciate any input. If you have any other questions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get rid of forward declarations entirely, but you can change the order so that you only need to forward declare `MessageHandler` and none of the messages:

```
struct MessageHandler;

struct Message {
    virtual void dispatch(MessageHandler&) = 0;
};

template<typename ActualMessage>
struct MessageHelper : Message {
    void dispatch(MessageHandler& handler);
};


struct MessageA : MessageHelper<GetDeviceConfig> {};
struct MessageB : MessageHelper<GetDeviceConfig> {};
// etc...

class MessageHandler {
public:
    virtual void handle(MessageA& m);
    virtual void handle(MessageB& m);
    // etc...

    virtual void handle(Message&) {}
};

template<typename ActualMessage>
void MessageHelper<ActualMessage>::dispatch(MessageHandler& handler)
{
    handler.handle(static_cast<ActualMessage&>(*this));
}
```

> I'm limited due to the fact that the MessageHelper class is templated. This restricts me in forward declaring the MessageHandler class instead.

It's unclear why you think `MessageHelper` being templated would restrict you from forward declaring `MessageHandler`.

Comment: Thanks! I now see that I can do it like this after all.